# global variable error while using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i am using tkinter in python to build a GUI.But i keep getting global variable error

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
global e1_value
def ext_data():
   global e1_value
   print(e1_value.get())
b1 = Button(window,text="Execute",comamand=ext_data())
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
e1_value=StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window,textvariable=e1_value)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
t1=Text(window,height=0,width=30)
t1.grid(row=0,column=2)
window.mainloop()
```

can anyone help me out 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use the `global` keyword when you are in the main `scope` (i.e. not in a `function`)...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i am sorry for not showing the error message .It was "global name 'e1_value' is not defined". However it is fixed now .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There were a few problems with this code, but the most important was the incorrect binding of a callback function to the button. You need to bind a function to the `command` property of an attribute (you wrote `comamand`).

This should accomplish your goals:

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

def ext_data():
  print(e1_value.get())

e1_value=StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=e1_value)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

b1 = Button(window, text="Execute", command=ext_data)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

t1=Text(window, height=0, width=30)
t1.grid(row=0, column=2)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you sir are a life saver
spelling of command was wrong . I don't get it , why didnt it gave me a syntax error

Comment: @shujaat: you didn't get a syntax error because python didn't have a chance to create the button. It executed your function before calling the `Button` constructor (so that it could pass the result to the constructor), and calling the function threw an error.